# Matplotlibcpp - Issue importing Python modules

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, matplotlib

I have seen this issue happening for mac OS users but I'm currently on windows10 and I don't know how to fix this.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017, and Python 2.7. However, I also have Python 3.7 and Anaconda in my PC, so I hope this is not messing up the linker to the proper libraries.

I'm using this library https://github.com/lava/matplotlib-cpp

In matplotlibcpp.h , line 137. I'm getting an exception:

```
Excepción producida en 0x00007FFFCF28E78A (ntdll.dll) en ConsoleApplication2.exe: 0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified.
```

This is the part of the code that fails (Line 137 being the PY_DECREF call to pyplotname)

```
PyObject* matplotlibname = PyString_FromString("matplotlib");
    PyObject* pyplotname = PyString_FromString("matplotlib.pyplot");
    PyObject* cmname  = PyString_FromString("matplotlib.cm");
    PyObject* pylabname  = PyString_FromString("pylab");
    if (!pyplotname || !pylabname || !matplotlibname || !cmname) {
      throw std::runtime_error("couldnt create string");
    }

    PyObject* matplotlib = PyImport_Import(matplotlibname);
    Py_DECREF(matplotlibname);
    if (!matplotlib) { throw std::runtime_error("Error loading module matplotlib!"); }

    // matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot,
    // or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time
    if (!s_backend.empty()) {
        PyObject_CallMethod(matplotlib, const_cast<char*>("use"), const_cast<char*>("s"), s_backend.c_str());
    }

    PyObject* pymod = PyImport_Import(pyplotname);
    Py_DECREF(pyplotname);
    if (!pymod) { throw std::runtime_error("Error loading module matplotlib.pyplot!"); }
```

When I type `import matplotlib.pyplot` in the terminal (using python2.7), it works perfectly:

[image: Importing pyplot in terminal]

If I manipulate the name in line 119, so instead of "matplotlib.pyplot" I write "matplotlib/pyplot", I reach the line 138 and it pops up the error message as expected.

So I guess it's finding the module but once he opens it, there is an error. Any ideas? I have seen a lot of post about this for Mac, but none for Windows.

These are my Path User:

[image: environmental variables]

These are my Path System:

[image: environmental variables]

I also have a PYTHONPATH in the System:

[image: environmental variables]

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: No, I'm not. @JackMoody

Comment: Please post your code as `formatted text`, not screenshots

Comment: Is it really necessary? Code can be found in the github file, I took screenshots to show a visual reference, but ok, I'll do @ForceBru

Answer (score 0):

I had a same error.  I am using anakonda python distribution. 
I fixed the error by reinstalling matplotlib.
**pip uninstall matplotlib
pip install matplotlib**

Make sure  following environment variables are defined at user level.
**PYTHONHOME**      C:\Anaconda3
**PYTHONPATH**      C:\Anaconda3
**QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH**        %PYTHONHOME%Library/plugins/platforms